# White bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap, wallpaper

I want to set home wallpaper with white bitmap:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(0xfff);

    WallpaperManager wall = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    try {
        wall.setBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the wallpaper becomes black. What's wrong is here?

Comment: What is the value of WIDTH and HEIGHT you are using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My first guess would be your color choice, assuming this is the value in your actual code and not edited.

Color ints in java take the form ARGB, so `Color.WHITE` is `0xFFFFFFFF`, `Color.BLUE` is `0xFF0000FF`, etc.

The color in **your** code (`0xFFF`) would expand to `0x00000FFF` which is Blue with a little green mixed in, but the **alpha** channel is zero, so the `Canvas` is basically written with a transparent color.

If you are using standard colors, I would stick to the constants in the `Color` class as parameters here, but if you want to define the color yourself, remember to place the full color or use `Canvas.drawRGB()` instead.

Answer (score 23):

Just add `bitmap.eraseColor(Color.WHITE);`

as second line